# What is the meaning of 業{ごう} in this line?

Tags: meaning

{{pad}}
ジブリの『もののけ姫』ではジコ坊はこう言います。

> 天土{あまつち}の間にある、全ての物を欲するは人の業{ごう}というものだ。

{{pad}}
上記の「人の業{ごう}」の意味がよく分かりません。「…全てのものを欲するのが人というものだ。」なら理解できますが、辞書を引いても「人の業{ごう}」はピンと来ませんでした。この言葉の意味を教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: どのような辞書を引かれました？　[デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/71613/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%94%E3%81%86/)でしたら、「ごう【業】3  理性によって制御できない心の働き。」に当たるのではないかと。明鏡国語辞典には、「ごう【業】➋理性ではどうすることもできない心の働き。」とあります

Comment: @Shoko 両方引きました。その定義読みましたが、宗教用語だし奥が深い感じがしましたので、一応質問を投稿しようかと思いました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

この「業」は、一般的には[*karma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma_in_Buddhism)と訳されます。主に仏教の用語なので難しく考えだすとキリがないのですが、普通の人は「将来の自分や子孫に（宗教的／倫理的な）影響を及ぼすような、何らかの行動」という程度に理解しています。通常は「[業が深い](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%A5%AD%E3%81%8C%E6%B7%B1%E3%81%84)」や「[自業自得](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/idiom/%E8%87%AA%E6%A5%AD%E8%87%AA%E5%BE%97/m0u/)」などのように、あまり良くない定型句で使われます。定型句以外では、現代人はむしろ「カルマ」の方を好んで使うかもしれません（こちらはそんなに悪い意味はありません）。

この文脈では「（良くはないが、避けることもできない）人間の本質的な行い」と捉えていればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なんとなく検討がついてきました。「避けられない行い・宿命」だけではなく、「未来に報いをもたらすであろう」というニュアンスもあるという理解でよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 通常はそうです。でも質問の例文だと「将来への報い」の意味は薄いと思います。

Comment: @DariusJahandarie この場合は、その行い自体が未来に報いる、というよりは、その行いをする定めが過去から背負わされている（だから宿命）、というニュアンスになると思います。

Answer (score 3):

Naruto's answer is good, but it never hurts to post a dictionary entry with example sentences.

[image]

---

Source: 新和英大辞典　第5版 ― 並装

Answer (score 0):

I've often thought that "*works*" makes a good translation for 業{ごう} in English.

So「**人の業**」, could translate to something like "**the works of men**".